# Understand Unix Diff Command

Tags: shell, unix, diff

I am trying to find the difference between two files, where-in i would like to know the new entries in file_2. For ex :

If a.txt contains:

```
a
b
c
```

And b.txt contains:

```
c
d
f
```

I would like to get `d and f`

I'm using the command : `diff --changed-group-format="%>" --unchanged-group-format=''`

```
mymach@dev-machine:~/test$ grep 'C:/Documents and Settings/pandep2/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/CrashpadMetrics.pma~RF115cef5.TMP' file_1.log
C:/Documents and Settings/pandep2/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/CrashpadMetrics.pma~RF115cef5.TMP

mymach@dev-machine:~/test$ grep 'C:/Documents and Settings/pandep2/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/CrashpadMetrics.pma~RF115cef5.TMP' file_2.log
C:/Documents and Settings/pandep2/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/CrashpadMetrics.pma~RF115cef5.TMP

mymach@dev-machine:~/test$ diff --changed-group-format="%>" --unchanged-group-format='' file_1.log file_2.log >diff_file.log

mymach@dev-machine:~/test$ grep 'C:/Documents and Settings/pandep2/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/CrashpadMetrics.pma~RF115cef5.TMP' diff_file.log
C:/Documents and Settings/pandep2/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/CrashpadMetrics.pma~RF115cef5.TMP
```

Since, the same file existed in both files, why would diff command still report that file?

Comment: Perhaps the location in each file is different?

Comment: $ echo "C:/Documents and Settings/pandep2/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/CrashpadMetrics.pma~RF115cef5.TMP" > file_1.log
$ cp file_1.log  file_2.log
$ diff --changed-group-format="%>" --unchanged-group-format='' file_1.log file_2.log
$

It should work. Your files obviously aren't matching

Comment: I never thought that location *does* play an important role, i always thought diff doesn't need a sorted file ?

Comment: does anyone have a better solution than diff for such scenario? I would really appreciate that.... i have two files which contain more than 1 million entries in each and i would like to find the difference of them.

Comment: i found a command : bash -c 'diff --changed-group-format="%>" --unchanged-group-format='' <(sort file_1.log) <(sort file_2.log) > diff_file.log'   is this good ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such scenario's, we are better of using the comm command in Unix.

for the above scenario, i have used:

```
comm -23 <(sort file_1.txt) <(sort file_2.txt)
```

This would give the unique files of file_1.txt

```
comm -13 <(sort a.txt) <(sort b.txt)
```

This would give the unique files of file_2.txt

```
comm -12 <(sort a.txt) <(sort b.txt)
```

This would give the common files between both files